# Error when concatenating CGFloat variable to multi-line String

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting a weird error when trying to concatenate a variable to a multi-line string.

**Error:** Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'

```
func getOpeningHTML() -> String
{
    let maxWidth:CGFloat = self.webView.frame.width

    return
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "body {" +
                "color: white;" +
                "padding:12px;" +
                "line-height:140%;" +
            "}" +
            "a:link {" +
                "color: #32b3e3;" +
            "}" +
            "img {" +
                "margin-top: 10px;" +
                "margin-bottom: 10px;" +
                "margin-right: 10px;" +
                "padding:2px; float: left;" +
                "clear: both;" +
                "border: 1px solid #637981;" +
                "max-width: \(maxWidth)px;" + // THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
            "}" +
            "img[alt~='Clothing'] { display: none; }" +
            "img[alt~='shop'] { display: none; }" +
            "img[alt~='AppHidden'] { display: none; }" +
        "</style>" +
        "</head><body>"
}
```

**Edit: Solution:**

```
let maxWidth:CGFloat = self.webView.frame.width

    var html:String = "<html>"
    html += "<head>"
    html += "<style type=\"text/css\">"
    html += "body {"
    html += "color: white;"
    html += "padding:12px;"
    html += "line-height:140%;"
    html += "}"
    html += "a:link {"
    html += "color: #32b3e3;"
    html += "}"
    html += "img {"
    html += "margin-top: 10px;"
    html += "margin-bottom: 10px;"
    html += "margin-right: 10px;"
    html += "padding:2px; float: left;"
    html += "clear: both;"
    html += "border: 1px solid #637981;"
    html += "max-width: \(maxWidth)px;"
    html += "}"
    html += "img[alt~='Clothing'] { display: none; }"
    html += "img[alt~='shop'] { display: none; }"
    html += "img[alt~='AppHidden'] { display: none; }"
    html += "</style>"
    html += "</head><body>"
    return html
```

Comment: It's a bug. File a report with Apple.

Comment: If you lookup the compiler messages in the Report navigator you will find: *"note: expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swift compiler has known problems with long concatenations. Better set a variable and do the concatenations line-by-line:

```
var s = "<html>"
s += "<head>"
...
return s
```

Answer (score 1):

As workaround in your example try to convert `maxWidth` to `String` and write as:

```
"max-width:" + String(maxWidth) + "px;"
```

---

```
func getOpeningHTML() -> String
{
    let maxWidth = 20

    return
        "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "body {" +
            "color: white;" +
            "padding:12px;" +
            "line-height:140%;" +
            "}" +
            "a:link {" +
            "color: #32b3e3;" +
            "}" +
            "img {" +
            "margin-top: 10px;" +
            "margin-bottom: 10px;" +
            "margin-right: 10px;" +
            "padding:2px; float: left;" +
            "clear: both;" +
            "border: 1px solid #637981;" +
            "max-width:" + String(maxWidth) + "px;" + 
            "}" +
            "img[alt~='Clothing'] { display: none; }" +
            "img[alt~='shop'] { display: none; }" +
            "img[alt~='AppHidden'] { display: none; }" +
            "</style>" +
    "</head><body>"
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence might be misleading. String interpolation works with integer variables as well, e.g. `return "max-width: \(maxWidth)px;"` compiles just fine. The compiler just chokes on the "complex" expression, and your `"max-width:" + String(maxWidth) + "px;"` seems to be a *workaround* for that compiler bug.

Comment: @MartinR this is what i mean,  String interpolation works with constants, variables, literals ... `" ... \(variables) ..."`. From Docs: `String and Character values can be added together (or concatenated) with the addition operator (+) to create a new String value:`. As I understand from this sentence, you need convert variables to String first

Comment: Your first sentence gives the impression that there is an error in OP's code (which is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning String in getOpeningHTML() and you have declared "maxwidth" as Int type. Don't forget about Swift's type inference.

Comment: His code is fine. The Int is converted to a String through the "\()" syntax.